# Retrieving Data from Firebase with certain ID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an ID of User, and i want to take his name from the firebase. So, i am trying to use orderByKey() method to find a certain user and after that, take information from his profile. But something goes wrong ...

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    Query query = reference.orderByKey().equalTo(task.author_id);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            fullName = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getFullName();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[Firebase Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCiTe.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a query in that case if you already know the specific path to that node. Just add the listener directly.

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
reference.child(task.author_id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        fullName = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getFullName();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```